# Javascript object passed in a function but apparently passed by value

Tags: javascript

As javascript objects are passesd by reference then why `console.log(obj1.a)` is showing 1 instead of 7. As function is changing value to 7.

```js
    obj1 = {
        a: 1
    }
    obj2 = {
        a: 1
    }
    
    function c(d) {
        console.log('d bef ', typeof d)
        
        if (typeof d === 'object'){
             
            d = obj2
        obj2.a = 7
        console.log ('d.a', d.a)
        }
        
    }
    c(obj1)
    console.log(obj1.a)
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn’t have pass by reference, and anyone who tries to create some kind of distinction between objects and primitives is wrong. You’re creating multiple references to the same object (the references are passed by value) and then replacing one of the references.

Comment: You have put `obj2.a = 7` so why would you even expect `obj1.a` to equal 7 regardless of value / reference types?

Comment: Because d = obj2. And d is the argument passed which is obj1

Comment: Even if JavaScript was passing by reference, you're modifying what `d` refers to inside your method.  `obj1.a` will not be changed by this method no matter how it gets passed.

Comment: No your just overriding your param. `d`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem confused by two different concepts.

In JS, objects ARE passed by references, but **variable** are not.

What does it means is that :

```js
//WHen you declare your VARIABLE, you assign it a REFERENCE to a new object :
const something = { property : 'foo' };

//Something now is a variable whose value is a REFERENCE to an object, not the object itself.

function success(obj){
    obj.property = 'bar';
}

function fail(obj){
    obj = { property : 'bar' }: 
}
//When you call fail : 

fail(something);
console.log(something.property); //will print foo

//When you call success : 

success(something);
console.log(something.property); //will print bar
```

In `success` function above, you access the object by reference through the function argument and you change its property. Because when you call `success`, the **variable** something pass its **reference** to the object by **value**. So, the argument of `success` (`obj`) has for **value** the **reference** to the object.

in `fail`, you replace the **reference** to the object by a reference to **another object**.

To be clear : the `something` **variable** is passed by **value**. But this value is a **reference** to an object.

Thus, you can change object properties through this reference, but you can't change the `something` variable value by assigning a new value to the function's parameter `obj`.

Comment: Objects are not “passed by reference”. You could say that objects are references, but it has nothing to do with passing.

Comment: No. An object IS actually an object. It's a data structure. A reference is a memory address pointing to that structure. When you call a function in JS, you pass your reference by value to the function parameter, whose is a new variable. So, you passed the reference, and its called "passing an object by reference". Because you gave to the function the reference to the said object. They are languages that allow to truly pass a reference to a variable, as with C. And, then, we would not say that we passed the object by reference, but the variable by reference.

Comment: “Passing a reference” is correct, but “pass by reference” is a very specific thing and JavaScript doesn’t have it at all (neither does C).

Comment: @Ry- You're trying to make a point on a vocabulary specific detail that is pointless and confusing. Passing a reference to an **object** by **value** is actually **passing an object by reference**, while **passing a reference** means actually **passing a variable by reference**. JS can do the first, because if it passed objects by value, they would be always copied and thus immutables. But can't do the last, I never argued against that. Sorry to insist on that point but it's a fact : It's perfectly right to say that *objects** are passed by reference in JS.

Comment: It’s not pointless – people repeatedly using this term incorrectly literally caused the very confusion in the question you’re answering. The behavior has *nothing to do with passing*; you can see it just by assigning the same object to different variables. (Also, separately, mentioning “object” – while not technically wrong – sort of implies there’s an observable difference in this regard between objects and non-objects, which there isn’t.)

Comment: It's far more confusing to affirm that "JavaScript doesn’t have pass by reference, and anyone who tries to create some kind of distinction between objects and primitives is wrong." In JS, there is a distinction between objects and primitive, in reguard of the way they are treated at assignement and in comparisons. If this distinction never existed, thus `let foo = 5, bar = 5; console.log(foo === bar)` would be false. It's actually true, because those two primives are... values. No references to a structure. Saying that there is no difference between objects and primitves in JS is just wrong.

Comment: There is no difference *with respect to how they are passed or assigned*.

Comment: Since objects are not copied at assignement time, and primitives are, there is a difference in assignement. Sorry. I can't agree on that statement. When you do `let bar = 5, foo = bar, baz = foo;` you allocate 3 JS integers. When you do `let foo = {}, bar = foo, baz = foo;`, you allocated memory for 1 object and kept 3 references to it.

Comment: “Copying” of primitives is an implementation detail, and not observable from JavaScript (the only intrinsic behavior that distinguishes them from immutable objects is not being able to be used as `WeakMap` keys). Note that a string is a JavaScript primitive type, but passing a large string to a function does not copy it.

Comment: Primitves ARE NOT objects in any means. They're wrapped with ephemeral objects when you call a method on them, but they stay primitves. They do not behave in the same way, either in reguard of their assignment nor the way they're passed from variable to variable, nor variable to parameters nor in memory. Primitives are not immutable objects, they CAN behave AS IF they where because they are temporarily wrapped with ephemeral boxes for simplicity sakes in some contexts. But this does not imply your statement at all. Just read MDN : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive

Comment: Primitive wrappers aren’t used for `this` in strict mode. It’s best to ignore their existence entirely, since they’re a useless misfeature. I wasn’t referring to them (notably, primitive wrappers are mutable). *“They do not behave in the same way, either in reguard of their assignment nor the way they're passed from variable to variable, nor variable to parameters…”* Completely wrong, but this is exactly the point. In all of those respects, the behavior of primitives is *indistinguishable* from immutable objects.

Comment: So, to sum it up : you're right against the documenation and pretty much every one out there ? And yet, you don't need to prove your point, because... hey. you know ou're right. that's it. Not only you don't source what you say, but you don't either make any proper demonstration that can validate your statements. I'm done here.

Comment: No, the docs link is fine; you’re just mistaken in thinking that it refutes anything I’m saying. (Incorrect information about this is *very* popular, though, and highly upvoted on SO, unfortunately.) If I’m wrong, it should be easy to prove: show code that distinguishes a primitive from an object using only its properties *in regard to their assignment, or the way it’s passed from variable to variable, or variable to parameter*. Harder to *prove* a negative, I’m afraid.

Comment: First, i already proved your wrong. You just ignored it or called it implementation detail. And YOU made a surprising statement. the burden of proof always rests with the person who makes a surprising assertion. Otherwise, i Can assert that the whole universe have been created by a galatic spacecake. Good chance to prove me that I'm wrong.

Comment: Do not see any agressivity in my comments. You challenge what I think I know. I studied and developped for years. I think I know how it works. If not, I'll be glad to learn it the right way. But you'd better be convincing

Comment: The difference between the origin of the universe and the claim of the existence of a particular kind of difference between two kinds of types in JavaScript is that it’s really easy to prove the latter by providing an example, which you still haven’t done.

Comment: I said : "let bar = 5, foo = bar, baz = foo; you allocate 3 JS integers. When you do let foo = {}, bar = foo, baz = foo;, you allocated memory for 1 object and kept 3 references to it.. "MDN says : "In JavaScript, a primitive (primitive value, primitive data type) is data that is not an object and has no methods or properties. " and about objects : "n computer science, an object is a value in memory which is possibly referenced by an identifier.","In JavaScript, objects can be seen as a collection of properties." Those quotes alone proves you're wrong, my example too.

Comment: You then asserted that some strings are not copied when too long. It's an optimisation detail, while variable assignement and memory allocation are not. Therefor immutable objects stays Objects, assigning objects accross variables and parameters only assign references to it, while primitves are copied. Even immutables objects are NOT copied. Now, please, provide source and/or proper demonstration for your statement. Without it, what you say is only opinion based.

Comment: I cleared up the discussion in an elaborate Reddit post. In short, pass-by-reference is a language-feature that was invented in C++. Passing objects which _are_ references is not the same as passing-by-reference. [See my full explanation](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjavascript/comments/wuq7oe/comment/ilbbwi8/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. In this reguard, and by better understanding your point, @Ry- I agree with you. That said, I still think that "anyone who tries to create some kind of distinction between objects and primitives is wrong" can be very ambiguous, especialy for those who just started to learn.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should have qualified that statement in that comment too. It’s about JavaScript-observable behaviors in contexts that beginners encounter, like the one in the question. (There’re even JavaScript-observable behavior differences, like the above `WeakMap`, or `this` wrapping outside of strict mode like you mentioned. Implementation details *are* differences, but not observable from within the program.) A lot of places imply that primitives work one way and objects another, and then learners are confused when they actually use them the *same* way and they work the same – like this Q.

Comment: I asked this question because i thought javascript and c++ pass by reference  are same thing. But i was wrong. In javascript passing an object as a parameter is same as passing a pointer as parameter in c++.

Answer (score 0):

By passing the data as a parameter, you pass the object value but not the reference, So, you have a new object with a new reference, just scoped for the function.

This is a simpler example.

```js
// The pet variable have the referance of the { type: 'cat' } object.
let pet = { type: 'cat' }

// p is a copy of the pet variable but not have the same referance.
const changeThePet = (p) => {
  p = { type: 'dog' }
}

// here you pass the pet variable
changeThePet(pet)

console.log(pet)
```

`p` will hold the value of the `pet` but they aren't the same `variable` or same `referance`

Comment: But i have heard objects are passed by reference. And in your example pet is a variable instead of object. But i am passing the object

Comment: Yes, the Object passed as a reference with equal assignment, for example, `let obj1 = obj2`, so `obj1` will hold the reference of `obj2`, but passing a parameter is a different thing, it only passes the value, whatever if the primitive type or reference type.